# Setting \tikzstyle inside \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, foreach

I am building a tree structure in tikz and am following [this texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/), which suggests adding styles for the children according to their depth in the tree (`first`, `second` and so on).
The purpose is that each level needs to adjust the `level distance` attribute. What I would like to do is use `\foreach` like so:

```
 \foreach \x / \y in {first/1,second/2,third/3,fourth/4,fifth/5,sixth/6,seventh/7,eight/8,ninth/9}
 {\tikzstyle{\x}=[level distance=\y*6 em]};
```

Or something of that sort, to set the distance for each level to a multiple of 6. The factor should depend on the level. I have tried to research how to use arithmetic in `\foreach` and came up with `\pgfmathparse{\y * 6}\pgfmathresult` to actually compute the number. So what I have is

```
 \foreach \x / \y in {first/1,second/2,third/3,fourth/4,fifth/5,sixth/6,seventh/7,eight/8,ninth/9}
 {\tikzstyle{\x}=[level distance=\pgfmathparse{\y * 6}\pgfmathresult em]};
```

And this compiles, but no styles are actually set. If I attempt to reference e.g. `first`, I get the `Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/first'`.
Maybe this has something to do with the order of macro expansion or some such magic.

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      work package/.style={draw,rectangle,text width=3cm},
      grandchild/.style={grow=down,
      edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |- ($(\tikzparentnode.south west) + (-1em,0)$) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
      first/.style={level distance=6ex},
      second/.style={level distance=14ex},
      third/.style={level distance=22ex},
      fourth/.style={level distance=30ex},
      fifth/.style={level distance=38ex},
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=2cm}
   ]   
   % \foreach \x / \y in {first/1,second/2,third/3,fourth/4,fifth/5,sixth/6,seventh/7,eight/8,ninth/9}
   % {\tikzstyle{\x}=[level distance=\pgfmathparse{\y * 6}\pgfmathresult em]};
   % Parents
   \coordinate
   node[work package, text centered] {Client-Server-System für Versicherung}
   [edge from parent fork down]
   % Children and grandchildren
   child{node[work package] {Phase 1}
      child[grandchild,first] {node[work package] {A: Funktionen erarbeiten}}
      child[grandchild,second] {node[work package] {B: Funktionen einteilen}}
      child[grandchild,third] {node[work package] {C: Schnittstellen zu Fremdsystemen}}
      child[grandchild,fourth] {node[work package] {D: Datenbankentwurf}}
      child[grandchild,fifth] {node[work package] {E: GUI-Prototyp entwickeln}}
   }   
   child{node[work package] {Phase 2}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \tikzstyle{\x}={stuff} is equivalent to \pgfkeys{/tikz/\x/.style={stuff}}.  Anyway, if you want to put it inside a \foreach lopp you will probably new \pgfextra to turn off the tikz parser.

Comment: The code in a `\foreach` loop is executed inside a group and so outside it the styles are not set.

Comment: Ok, any way to fix that? Somehow export them out of their scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping close to the OP's code, here is way which uses package [xinttools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) for its `\xintForpair` loop. The syntax is a bit different from the `\foreach` one, but the important thing here is that the items are not executed inside groups.

Besides there were other problems in the OP's code inside the `\foreach` in the way the `\pgfmathparse` was used, but anyhow it was not needed in the end.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xinttools}% for \xintForpair loop 

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      work package/.style={draw,rectangle,text width=3cm},
      grandchild/.style={grow=down,
      edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |-
        ($(\tikzparentnode.south west) + (-1em,0)$) |-
        (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
% commented-out from OP's code:
      % first/.style={level distance=6ex},
      % second/.style={level distance=14ex},
      % third/.style={level distance=22ex},
      % fourth/.style={level distance=30ex},
      % fifth/.style={level distance=38ex},
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=2cm}
   ] 
% This can not work because \foreach items are executed inside groups
%
% besides, the \pgfmathparse should have been done before the \tikzstyle
% and only \pgfmathresult used in level distance key value
% 
% \foreach \x / \y in {first/1,second/2,third/3,fourth/4,fifth/5,sixth/6,seventh/7,eight/8,ninth/9}
% {\tikzstyle{\x}=[level distance=\pgfmathparse{\y * 6}\pgfmathresult em]};
%
% from package xinttools, a looping with a slightly different syntax:
%
   \xintForpair #1#2 in
   {(first,1),(second,2),(third,3),(fourth,4),(fifth,5),(sixth,6),(seventh,7),(eight,8),(ninth,9)} \do
   {\tikzstyle{#1}=[level distance=6*#2 em]}
% (turns out 6*#2 is correctly parsed directly)
%
   % Parents
   \coordinate
   node[work package, text centered] {Client-Server-System für Versicherung}
   [edge from parent fork down]
   % Children and grandchildren
   child{node[work package] {Phase 1}
      child[grandchild,first] {node[work package] {A: Funktionen erarbeiten}}
      child[grandchild,second] {node[work package] {B: Funktionen einteilen}}
      child[grandchild,third] {node[work package] {C: Schnittstellen zu Fremdsystemen}}
      child[grandchild,fourth] {node[work package] {D: Datenbankentwurf}}
      child[grandchild,fifth] {node[work package] {E: GUI-Prototyp entwickeln}}
   }   
   child{node[work package] {Phase 2}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz tree with xintForpair]

Comment: I like this answer best since it's closest to what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this without a loop :

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
         work package/.style={draw,rectangle,text width=3cm},
         grandchild/.style={grow=down,
         edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |- ($(\tikzparentnode.south west) + (-1em,0)$) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
         child/.style={level distance={(#1*8-2)*1ex}},
         level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=2cm}
      ]
      % Parents
      \coordinate
      node[work package, text centered] {Client-Server-System für Versicherung}
      [edge from parent fork down]
      % Children and grandchildren
      child{node[work package] {Phase 1}
         child[grandchild,child=1] {node[work package] {A: Funktionen erarbeiten}}
         child[grandchild,child=2] {node[work package] {B: Funktionen einteilen}}
         child[grandchild,child=3] {node[work package] {C: Schnittstellen zu Fremdsystemen}}
         child[grandchild,child=4] {node[work package] {D: Datenbankentwurf}}
         child[grandchild,child=5] {node[work package] {E: GUI-Prototyp entwickeln}}
      }
      child{node[work package] {Phase 2}};

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is a code using counter for auto-shifting.

```
  \documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{trees,calc}

  \newcounter{child}

  \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
           work package/.style={draw,rectangle,text width=3cm},
           grandchild/.style={grow=down,
           edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |- ($(\tikzparentnode.south west) + (-1em,0)$) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
           grandchild/.append code={\stepcounter{child}\pgfkeysalso{level distance={\thechild*4ex-2ex}}},
           level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm,level distance=2cm}
        ]
        % Parents
        \coordinate
        node[work package, text centered] {Client-Server-System für Versicherung}
        [edge from parent fork down]
        % Children and grandchildren
        child{node[work package] {Phase 1}
           child[grandchild] {node[work package] {A: Funktionen erarbeiten}}
           child[grandchild] {node[work package] {B: Funktionen einteilen}}
           child[grandchild] {node[work package] {C: Schnittstellen zu Fremdsystemen}}
           child[grandchild] {node[work package] {D: Datenbankentwurf}}
           child[grandchild] {node[work package] {E: GUI-Prototyp entwickeln}}
        }
        child{node[work package] {Phase 2}};

     \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only because it is a tree... but it does make the tree specification nice and concise... [But I can't figure out how to make it break the lines automatically within the nodes.]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      draw,
      text width=3cm,
      align=left,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(-10pt,0pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      where level=0{
        parent anchor=south,
        l sep+=10pt,
      }{
        where level=1{
          parent anchor=west,
          child anchor=north,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-7.5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
        }{
          parent anchor=west,
          child anchor=west,
        },
      },
    }
       [Client-Server-\\System für\\Versicherung, text centered, align=center
         [Phase 1
           [A: Funktionen\\erarbeiten
             [B: Funktionen\\einteilen
               [C: Schnittstellen\\zu Fremdsystemen
                 [D: Datenbanken-\\twurf
                   [E: GUI-Prototyp\\entwickeln
                   ]
                 ]
               ]
             ]
           ]
         ]
         [Phase 2
         ]
       ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]